# determine the depth of a tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

Is there a data structure designed to find the depth of a tree(not a binary tree) quickly?

Is the D-forest ok? 
I need more details about the data structure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a number in every node of the tree that is the depth of the tree below the node. On insertion or deletion, you'll have to recompute the values at all the nodes from the root to the affected node. Would this work for you?

Comment: @user900168: I am also an infrequent visitor to this site. I think you can mark this answer "accepted" by clicking on the check mark next to it.